# Single pipeline mapped to multiple git repositories

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have configured 8 git repos [webhook](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline) mapped to single pipeline(Jenkins).

This is a scripted pipeline(groovy).

Single pipeline gets triggered based on  push/merge event happening on any of the 8 repos.

The pipeline is supposed to checkout `develop` branch based on the repository that triggered the pipeline. `env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'` says that pushed branch is `develop`

So, on trigger, groovy script would perform `git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${env.GIT_URL_1}")`

---

Can scripted pipeline rely on `env.GIT_URL_N` that can provide the information about, which repository(`.git`) triggered the scripted pipeline? so that groovy script can read `env.GIT_URL_N` and perform checkout on `develop` branch..

https://github.com/danger/danger/pull/607

Answer (score 1):

You can just use "${gitlabSourceBranch}" variable if your pipeline is **not a** multi-branch pipeline. (**if you are using GITLAB**)

So it would like something:-

> git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitlabSourceBranch}")

Comment: How to retrieve branch name ?

Comment: ${BRANCH_NAME} or env.BRANCH_NAME

Comment: How `${BRANCH_NAME}` different from `${env.BRANCH_NAME}`?

Comment: Read third question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55083441/11115740). `${env.gitlabSourceBranch}` does not work