# What should remotes/origin/HEAD set to?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, git-remote

If the developers are working on `develop` branch, for a new project

## 1) Clone

`git clone <git_url>` should be able to automatically clone `develop` branch locally without using `-b` option, so that

```
$ git branch -a # after clone should give
* develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
```

## 2) Push

When developer pushes local branch(`develop`) changes to remote repository(`origin/develop`) using command `git push origin develop`, my understanding is, changes are pushed to `origin/master`, **if** `remotes/origin/HEAD` points to `origin/master`, unlike mentioned in this [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/255346/what-does-master-mean-in-git-push-origin-master#comment506058_255350)

---

**Question:**

1)
Is it recommended to run `git remote set-head origin develop` and set `HEAD` pointer in remote repository, before performing above two tasks? by any developer

2)
Does `git push origin develop` pushes changes `origin/develop` irrespective of `remotes/origin/HEAD` value in remote repository?

3)
We use webhook between GitLab & Jenkins. Does `env.gitlabSourceBranch` provided by [GitLab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin), gives branch name that `remotes/origin/HEAD` point to? If yes, how to get the branch name on which, push event happen? through webhook.

Below are the settings done in GitLab, to retrieve branch name on which new commit occured:

[image]
Below is the code in Jenkins:

```
node('worker_node'){

    stage('stage1'){

        def repoName = env.gitlabSourceRepoName
        println "Repository Name: " + repoName // gives correct repo name


        def branchName = env.gitlabSourceBranch
        println "Branch name: " + branchName // gives always 'master' as value
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you wanna push develop to remote and not keep master ? Better keep master and develop. If there is some other business need leme know I will guide you on that .

Here you can rename ur current branch to master like `git branch -m master` and checkout to new branch `git checkout -b develop` now push your develop branch to remote server `git push origin develop -u` this will set upstream to develop branch.

Comment: If you are using git clone it will automatically set remote origin. 
you only need to set-remote url in case you have started making local git repo from `git init` or you wanna change remote url.

`git checkout -b <branchName>` is used if you wanna create local branch. 
`git checkout <branch>` will pull branch from remote if existed. 
better run `git fetch` before `checkout` to get info of newly created branches 

In jeckins you don't need to set remote urls it only takes branch name and base url of repo.

leme knwo if you are clear

Answer (score 3):

> Is it recommended to run `git remote set-head origin develop` and set `HEAD` pointer in remote repository ...

This might be a language issue, but it's worth pointing out here that this *doesn't* set `HEAD` in the remote repository.  It has *no effect* on anyone else's `git clone` command.

Git's terminology here is very confusing.  Let's break it down a bit:

- A *remote* is a short name you use in your Git repository to refer to some other Git repository.  Hence `origin` is a remote: it stands in for some URL.  If your Git dials that URL, some other Git answers this "phone call".  Note that the word *remote* here is a noun: it is a thing on its own.
- A *remote repository* is a repository other than your own.  When you have your Git dial some URL and call some other Git, that other Git is a *remote repository*.  The word *remote* here is an adjective.
- The word *branch* is rather ambiguous in Git.  (See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))  I prefer to use the phrase *branch name*, where *branch* is an adjective modifying *name*, and *remote-tracking name* (Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name*), which has an entire adjective phrase modifying the word *name*, to refer to things like `master` and `origin/master` respectively.

  The word *branch* can also mean a vaguely-defined series of commits.  In this particular set of circumstances—where we use `git clone` to copy a Git repository from some URL to our own machine, or `git push` to send commits from our Git repository on our machine to some other Git repository elsewhere (probably on another machine)—we won't need this other sense of the word.  But be aware that it exists!

We also need one more or two more pieces of Git terminology:

- A *reference* (or *ref*) is a branch name, tag name, or other similar name.  In fact, *reference* is just a generalization of these: branch names, tag names, and remote-tracking names are all just specific *kinds* of references.  A reference has a full spelling that starts with `refs/`.

  This is usually immediately followed by its classification: for instance, all branch names start with `refs/heads/`.  That, in fact, is *how* Git knows that `refs/heads/master` *is* a branch.  All tag names start with `refs/tags/`, which is how Git knows that `refs/tags/v1.2` is a tag, and all remote-tracking names start with `refs/remotes/`.

  In most cases you can drop the `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` or `refs/remotes/` part of a reference.  If you just say `master`, for instance, Git will search through all of your references.  If you have a `refs/heads/master` and no `refs/tags/master`, the name `master` must be *that* branch name, so Git will treat it that way—as a branch.  Likewise, if you just say `v2.1`, and Git searches and finds a tag named `refs/tags/v2.1` but nothing else, then `v2.1` must be *that* tag name, so Git will treat it that way—as a tag.

  All of the remote-tracking names that your Git uses to remember names on the Git your Git calls `origin` start with `refs/remotes/origin/`.  That is, your Git remembers *their* `master` as *your* `origin/master`.  This is so that if you have another remote, it's not ambiguous which *other* `master` you mean.  Suppose, for instance, that you add a second remote—a third Git repository—that you call `upstream` for short.  If the Git at the URL you call `upstream` has a `master` branch, your Git will call that `upstream/master`, and it's easy to tell this apart from the thing your Git calls `origin/master`.
- A *refspec* is, in its second-simplest form, a *pair of references* with a colon `:` stuck between them.  Hence `master:master` is a refspec, for instance.  So is `refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.  The thing on the left of the colon is the *source*, and the thing on the right of the colon is the *destination*.

The `git fetch` and `git push` commands use refspecs, as we will see in a moment.  While you're asking about `git clone` rather than `git fetch`, a significant part of `git clone` is that it *runs* `git fetch`.

With all of this in mind, let's look next at *how* Git resolves a symbolic name, and *when* Git resolves a symbolic name.  This part is a bit tricky because `git fetch` and `git push` use *positional arguments*.

Removing a lot of detail (such as flag arguments), the arguments to `git push` and `git fetch` are spelled out this way in the documentation:

`git fetch` *[`repository`] [`refspec` [`refspec` ...]]*
        `git push` *[`repository`] [`refspec` [`refspec` ...]]*

That is, after the `push` or `fetch` sub-command, the *next* item, if there is a next item, *is*, by definition, a *`repository`*.  Any items *after* the *`repository`* arguments are, by definition, *`refspec`* arguments.  You can put a raw URL in for the repository part, but in general, you should use a remote name, for two reasons:

- it's easier to type and get right; and
- it enables useful special features.

To put in any *`refspec`* arguments, you *have to* insert a *`repository`* argument, because without one, Git will just think that whatever you typed *is* a *`repository`* argument.  That is, if you accidentally run `git push master`, Git won't figure out that you meant to type `git push origin master`.  It will just try to treat `master` as a remote, or failing that, as a URL.  Probably it won't work either way and you'll get this puzzling output:

```
$ git push master
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So with `git push`, you have options like this:

```
git push
git push origin
git push origin somebranch
git push origin branch1:branch1 branch2:branch2 branch3 tag1:tag1
```

When you leave stuff out, as in the first two examples, Git picks the remote and refspec for you (first example), or the refspec for you (second example).  When you include a refspec (third example) or multiple refspecs (fourth example), you control all the parts.

Let's go on to your second question now, before we come back to the first:

> Does `git push origin develop` pushes changes `origin/develop` irrespective of `remotes/origin/HEAD` value in remote repository?

This contains multiple terminology errors (again they might just be language issues).  The overall idea is, I think, clear enough, though, and the answer is yes: this totally disregards `remotes/origin/HEAD`.

To be explicit, this:

- specifies `origin` as the remote, and
- specifies `develop` as the refspec.

Remember that we said that the *second* simplest form of refspec is a *pair* of names with a colon between them.  This uses the *most* simple form, which omits the second name.  The behavior of omitting the second name is different in `push` and `fetch`.  Let's only worry about `push` here.

For `git push`, omitting the second part of a refspec means *first part and second part are the same*.  That is, `develop` *means* `develop:develop`.  The name `develop` itself is short—it doesn't start with `refs/`—but both your Git and their Git probably have a *branch* named `develop` and no *tag* named `develop`.<sup>1</sup>  So `develop` is actually short for `refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop` here.

Remember that their Git repository *is* a Git repository.  It therefore has *its own* `refs/heads/develop`—its own branch name spelled `develop`.  *Your* `refs/heads/develop` identifies some commit in *your* repository.  *Their* `refs/heads/develop` identifies some commit in *their* repository.

When you run `git push`, you tell *your* Git: *Connect to some other Git.  Then make sure they have enough commits and other internal Git objects to achieve the last part, by giving them any commits I have that they don't that they will need.  Last, you've finished that, ask them—or command them—to set some of **their** branch and/or tag names to point to some particular commits or other appropriate Git objects.*

The branch and/or tag names that you will ask *them* to set come from the *destination* part of the refspec.  So if you said `git push ... develop:develop`, the branch or tag name you'll have your Git ask their Git to change is `develop`.  The *commit* you'll ask them to set as their `develop` is the one identified by the source name—the one on the right.  So you're going to ask them to set *their* `develop` to identify the same commit that *your* `develop` identifies.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you *do* have both a branch `refs/heads/develop` *and* a tag `refs/tags/develop`, some not-very-good things happen.  Git has rules for this, but Git's rules are a bit weird and unsettling.  Your best bet is to avoid this situation entirely: never use the same short name for both a tag and a branch.

---

#### They can say either yes or no

**If they say yes to this request**, your Git now knows that their `develop` represents that commit.  Your Git *remembers* their `develop` by updating your own `origin/develop`.  So your Git updates *your* `origin/develop`—your `refs/remotes/origin/develop`, to use its full name—to save that commit hash ID.

Note that nowhere in this process did your Git look at your own `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  You didn't put `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` on the left side of your refspec.  You *could* do that if you wanted.  For instance, you could write:

```
git push origin refs/remotes/origin/HEAD:refs/heads/develop
```

This will have your Git resolve your `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to a commit hash ID, call up the Git over at `origin`, and ask *that* Git to set *their* `refs/heads/develop` to that commit hash ID.  It probably already *is* set to that ID so this is probably just a waste of time, but it is something you could run, if you wanted.

You can also run:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/develop
```

which resolves your `HEAD` to a commit hash ID, calls up the Git over at `origin`, and asks them to set their branch `develop` based on that; and you can run:

```
git push origin a123456:refs/heads/develop
```

if `a123456` is some valid commit in your repository.  Most of these forms require the two-part refspec, with the colon in it, because the thing on the left of the colon here is not necessarily a branch name at all, and you're going to want to ask *their* Git to set one of their branch names.

In general, though, when using `git push`, you will start with your own branch name or names (like `develop` and/or `master`) and want to ask them to set *their* branch names, of the *same* name, to the same commit hash ID.  Occasionally—such as after you've just made a new tag name—you will want to have your Git call up their Git and ask them to set a new tag of the same name, to the same hash ID.  So `git push`'s default of mirroring the one name into two serves you well, because you can just write:

```
git push origin master develop v1.3
```

and thereby ask them to set *both* of their branches, *and* create a new tag, all in one go.

**If they say no, they can do it piecemeal.**  Suppose you ask them to set all three of these names, and they accept your request to update their `develop` and create a new `v1.3`, but reject your request to update their `master`.  You'll get two successes one one failure, and your Git will update your `refs/remotes/origin/develop` to remember the branch success, but not update your `refs/remotes/origin/master` because the branch failure means you don't know what their `master` is after all.  (There is no such thing as a *remote tag* so success or failure at asking them to create `v1.3` has no effect on any names in your repository.)

#### Back to `origin/HEAD`: what is it and what good is it?

To put it briefly (and maybe slightly *too* aggressively), `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is useless.

What it *is* is a symbolic reference that your Git has.<sup>2</sup>  You can set it, any time you like, using `git remote set-head origin`.  It's initially created during `git clone`.  But it has, as far as I can tell, *no* practical purpose whatsoever.

I mentioned above that you can shorten references: you can say `master` to mean `refs/heads/master` and `v2.1` to mean `refs/tags/v2.1`.  Try this sort of thing in your own Git repository: run `git rev-parse` and give it short and long names for branches and tags.  (Use `git branch` to list your branches, and `git tag` to list your tags.)  You will see things like this:

```
$ git rev-parse master
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a
$ git rev-parse v2.1.0
7452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20
```

The rev-parse command translates from a symbolic name, like `master`, to a hash ID, like `b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`.  (It can also translate from a short hash ID to a full one, or do many other tricks, but that's one of its main jobs: to turn a name into a hash ID.)

In general, when you give Git a short name, Git searches through all your references to figure out what the long one is.  The `git rev-parse` command does this and then spits out the hash ID.  Most other Git commands *also* do this, but then go on to *use* the hash ID in some way.  In almost all cases, though,<sup>3</sup> this searching process is outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is worthy of close and careful study over time.  But take a quick look at it now and scroll down just a little bit to find a six-step list.

The six-step list here is *how* Git turns a short name into a long one.  Note that it's step 3 that tries `v2.1` as a tag name: if `refs/tags/v2.1` exists, then `v2.1` is a tag name, and that's how `git rev-parse` knows and finds its hash ID.  It's step 4 that tries `master` as a branch name: if `refs/heads/master` exists, then `master` is a branch name and that's how `git rev-parse` knows.

Down at the bottom of the six-step list, there is a step 6.  This last step takes whatever string you typed in—which could be `origin`, for instance—and tries it as `refs/remotes/string/HEAD`.  If that exists, that must be what you meant.  So while `origin` is typically a *remote*—it's what you type in as the *`repository`* argument for `git fetch` and `git push`—it's *also* a valid short name for a *commit*, if you put it in a place where some Git command, like `git rev-parse`, will *use* it as a commit.

It's possible to *remove* `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and `git remote origin set-head -d` does exactly that.  If you have removed it, `origin` won't match step 6 and `git rev-parse origin` will just fail.  It's possible to use `git remote origin set-head` to *change* the name stored in your `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to any other `origin/*` branch name, so that step 6 succeeds but uses that other name.  None of this *ever* goes back to the other Git over at `origin`!

---

<sup>2</sup>I'm glossing over *symbolic reference* here.  A symbolic reference occurs when a name like `HEAD` contains, instead of the hash ID of some Git object, another name.  The mechanism that Git uses is intended to be general, but is full of weird quirks and flaws, and actually really only works right with `HEAD`, and—to a lesser extent—with these remote-tracking `origin/HEAD` style names.

You can, for instance, create your own symbolic references in the branch name space.  Using `git symbolic-ref refs/heads/INDIR refs/heads/master` creates the name `INDIR` as a symbolic reference branch.  Unfortunately, if you do this and then attempt to *delete* the name `INDIR`, Git deletes the name `master` instead!  The whole thing is not really ready for this sort of use (abuse?).  Don't do it!

<sup>3</sup>I say *almost all cases* because certain Git commands *know* that their name argument is a branch or tag name, and others *suspect* it.  For instance, `git branch` *knows* that you are going to give it a branch name, not a tag name, as the next argument.  So it doesn't use the six-step resolution process, and in fact, it demands that you *not* spell a branch name with the full `refs/heads/` form when you create a new branch.

The `git checkout` command is the weirdest, because the positional argument after `checkout` (and any flags) is allowed to be a branch name, a tag name, or anything that resolves to a valid commit.  So it seems like it *should* use the six-step process.  If you create a branch and tag both named `X` but pointing to two different commits, you might expect `git checkout X` to check out the the *tagged* `X`.  In fact, though, it checks out the *branch*.  So while `git checkout` *will* try all six steps, it tries step 4 *earlier* than step 3.

(Technically, it isn't going through the six-step process when it tries the name as a branch name.  Instead, it just tries it as a branch name first.  If that works, `git checkout` puts you on the branch and is done.  If it fails, *then* the code calls the six-step name-to-ID-resolver, and as long as a commit hash comes back, `git checkout` puts you on a detached HEAD on that commit.  So it actually tries step 4 twice, as it were—but if it failed the first time, it's extremely likely to fail the second time too.)

---

#### How `git clone` works

When you run `git clone url`, you have Git:

1. Create a new, empty directory (or take over some existing empty directory).  The remaining steps all happen *in* that directory.
2. Run `git init` to create an empty Git repository.
3. Run `git remote add` to create a remote.  The name of this remote is whatever you chose with your `-o` flag, but if you didn't choose one, it's just `origin`.  The URL for this new remote is the URL you gave to `git clone`.
4. Set some default refspecs for `git fetch`.  The actual refspecs depend on command-line flags, but a typical standard one is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  Note how closely this resembles the refspecs we were using for `git push`.  Configure the symbolic HEAD for this remote as if by `git remote set-head`.  Run any additional `git config` commands specified by additional command-line flags.
5. Run `git fetch`.  This uses the remote created in step 3 and the refspecs set in step 4.
6. Run `git checkout name`.  The *name* argument to this step depends on command line flags *and* on information obtained from the other Git.  See below for details.

It's step 6 that puts your new clone on `master` or, perhaps, on `develop`, or even on no branch at all if you chose something like `v2.1` here.  If step 6 puts you on your `master` branch, that's what *creates* your `master` branch.  If step 6 puts you own your `develop` branch, that's what *creates* your `develop` branch.  If step 6 leaves you with a detached HEAD, your Git doesn't create any branches!

You can, if you like, specify *which name* this last clone step should use, using `git clone -b name`.  If you do that, *nothing the other Git says matters*, except of course that *`name`* has to match one of its names.  But if you *don't* use a `-b` argument, then—and only then—what the other Git says matters a lot.

The other Git repository *is* a Git repository.  This means the other Git repository—let's call it the server repository for simplicity—has a `HEAD`.  The `HEAD` in the server repository tells which branch is checked-out in the server repository.  If the server repository is a `--bare` repository, it has no work-tree, so its `HEAD` is *somewhat* irrelevant.  But it still *has* one, and that means there's still one that the server is "on", unless the server's Git is in detached HEAD mode (which is possible).

When your Git calls up the server Git, one of the things your Git can ask the server is:  *Which branch are you on?*  That is, your Git can ask the server about the *server's* `HEAD`.  If you fail to specify a chosen branch for `-b` during `git clone`, *that's* the name that your Git will use for *your* `git checkout`.

That's also the name that your Git will use for your `git remote set-head origin --auto`, and the name that your `git clone` will set up automatically as your `origin/HEAD`.  So the *server's* `HEAD` setting is the default for your `origin/HEAD` copy at `git clone` time, *and* the default for the last-step-of-clone `git checkout` command.

That's *all* it really is good for.  If you override it with `-b` at `git clone` time, *that* meaning doesn't matter, and since `origin/HEAD` is quite useless anyway, *that* meaning doesn't matter either.

#### Conclusion

Don't worry about `origin/HEAD`.  It's useless.  It doesn't do you any good.

Don't worry *much* about `HEAD` in the server repository.  It does affect new clones, but only if the person doing the clone doesn't pick a branch.  If you do want to set it, you can do that however your server allows.  (Different web services have different ways to set or change this.)

Last, regarding this question:

> We use webhook between GitLab & Jenkins

I know nothing about the particular plugin you are using.  Jenkins documentation varies: some of it is slightly useful, most of it seems to be missing, and some of it seems to be just plain wrong.  In general Jenkins gets notifications *from* whatever hosting server you use, that something has happened, and then you write code that decodes the event(s) that occurred.  But this part:

> how to get the branch name on which push event happen(s)

is a fundamentally bad question, because there isn't necessarily *any* branch name—we might `git push` to a tag only, for instance—and if there *is* a branch name, there might be *many* branch names, and they might have changed hash IDs, or not.  The right question to ask is whether it's appropriate to have Jenkins start some pipeline(s).  I can't really help *answer* that, but this is your guide to asking the right questions.

Comment: For the last para, in your answer, Query edited for 3rd question

Comment: It looks like `env.gitlabSourceBranch` is not set to anything useful in that particular Jenkins script, then. I've never found any adequate Jenkins documentation—it's so bad that I'm surprised anyone uses it, as it's a bit like a car with three foot pedals, none of which is a brake pedal, and no steering wheel and no instructions on how to steer it...